# Atom: Find and Replace with Incrementing Number

Tags: replace, find, sublimetext, atom-editor

Is it possible in Atom, or Sublime Text, to use Find and Replace on the word "item" and have it replace item with "item`[i]`", where `[i]` is a number starting from 1?

I've got a bunch of items that look like this:

```
item1
item1
item1
item1
item1
```

And I'd like them to look like this:

```
item1
item2
item3
item4
item5
```

Random question, I know. Just wanted to know if it was possible.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just want to add that Notepad++ got a default function for this. (Don't want to put it in answer as you are asking for sublimetext or atom-editor only)

Answer (score 3):

For Sublime, install the [`Increment Selection`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Increment%20Selection) plugin via [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/). Next, do a regex search for `(?!:item)(1)`:

[image]

Click <kbd>Find All</kbd> to select all the `1`s:

[image]

Next, hit either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> (OS X) to run the `increment` command:

[image]

and the numbers are now incremented.

If you're looking for something more complex, check out [`Text Pastry`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Text%20Pastry). It has many many more features for working with multiple selections.

Comment: Any reason for downvoting?

Comment: The keyboard in macOS was ctrl+cmd+i last time I tried.